# Autocomplete won't work in pyqt5 when use PushButton,LineEdit and .

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I'm new to Python and like write code in pyqt
I'm  write simple code but autocomplate not show in my ide for pushbutton and other widget

[image: My code]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets,uic
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget,QMainWindow,QPushButton,QLabel,QLineEdit,QComboBox,QWidget
import time
from os import system

class MyForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyForm,self).__init__()
        loadUi("library.ui",self)
        self.setWindowTitle("salam")  

    def onclick(self):
        self.pushbu

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyForm()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: If you're referring to the autocompletion of objects you created in the ui, it's not possible. Those objects are created dynamically on runtime using the provided ui file.

Comment: Part of your issue is using a UI instead of coding a Python-Qt application as it was meant to be coded.  The Designer or anything that produces a UI file purpose was to make a generic GUI that could be used with different languages (e.g. C++ and Python) simultaneously -- so unless you needing this functionality you should code your GUI using Python-Qt as it should be used as then you are depending upon "Black-Box Untouchable Code" which is always a very bad idea in any project.